# Removing TextViews when i clicked backbutton

Tags: java, android, android-activity, textview

My problem is I have a button and that button is doing create new textview but that textviews removing when i click back button. How I saved textviews in activity?

```
My java sourcecodes here
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notlar);
        Button btnNotEkle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNotEkle);
        final EditText etNot = new EditText(NotEkle.this);
        final LinearLayout layoutNotlar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutNotlar);
        final TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvnotOrtalama);
        etNot.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        AlertDialog.Builder notEkle = new AlertDialog.Builder(NotEkle.this);
        notEkle.setTitle("Notunuz");
        notEkle.setView(etNot);

        //Positive button
        notEkle.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            tvNot = new TextView(NotEkle.this);//girelen not burdaki textview e yazdırılacak.
            girilenNot = etNot.getText().toString();//Girilen notu alıyoruz
            tvNot.setText(girilenNot);//girilen notu textviewa veriyoruz
            notTopla += Integer.parseInt(girilenNot);//Notları topluyoruz
            layoutNotlar.addView(tvNot);
            count = layoutNotlar.getChildCount();
            dersOrtalamaYazdir=String.valueOf(dersOrtalama());
            tv1.setText("Ders Ortalamanız : "+dersOrtalamaYazdir);
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog notEkleCreate = notEkle.create();
        btnNotEkle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                notEkleCreate.show();
            }
        });
    }



}
```

Comment: please show us Your onBackPressed() implementation...

Comment: i havent onBacPressed(). When i click back button on emulator textviews removing

Comment: Your `TextView` is inside dialog?

Comment: yes my friend @Yurets

Answer (score 1):

Try giving your `TextView` objects ids.

You need to know that when you click back button - by default your activity is destroyed so all views are removed.

When you are adding new `TextView` you should add information about this `TextView` (like the text itself) to some list declared as field in your activity.
Then you can save this list when activity is recreated see:  [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))/[nRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

You can also pass this list back or to new activity so that they can take actions based on this list.

Comment: But i havent list? :/ and can you write an example for saveInstanceState?

Comment: @FurkanKELES How does this activity work? You click back button and navigate to previous screen and then go back to this activity again expecting your new `TextView`s there?

Comment: yes. I have button previous screen when i click button startActivity and i go textview's activity but i see clean extremely white page :(

Comment: @FurkanKELES, @questioner, is right, for this purpose use `onSaveInstanceState/nRestoreInstanceState`, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @FurkanKELES When you add new textview add it's content to ArrayList<String> declared in you activity. Then override onBackPressed() method, and save your ArrayList to SharedPreferences. The when you are next time in this screen, get your ArrayList from preferences and recreate views. You need to know that each time you call startActivity() fresh activity is created so if you save what you need to preferences - you can get it back any time

Answer (score 0):

Following my understanding your `TextView` had been created inside `Dialog` and after you press back button the dialog dismisses and all views you created inside will be removed and you can't access it from your `Activity`.

You may try to create `TextView` in `onCreate`, pass and in `Dialog` just call `setText`. I hope this is the answer you're looking for.
Cheers.

Comment: I cant create in onCreate. I must create in Dialog

Comment: @FurkanKELES, unfortunately you cannot access it from within `activity` this way. if you destroy component where `view` was created you will destroy and view itself.